# Реализация метода удаления узла в бинарном дереве

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать метод для данного класса. Пробовал писать метод по разным алгоритмам, что нашел, но в итоге ничего не вышло.

```
 public class BinaryTree {
    public static class Node {
        int    key;
        String value;
        Node   leftChild;
        Node   rightChild;
        Node(int key, String name) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Key: " + key + " Value:" + value;
        }
    }

    private Node root;

    public void addNode(int key, String value) {
        // Создаем новый узел:
        Node newNode = new Node(key, value);
        if (root == null) { // первый добавленный узел
            root = newNode;
        }
        else {
            // Начинаем обход:
            Node currentNode = root;
            Node parent;
            while (true) {
                parent = currentNode;
                // Проверяем ключи:
                if (key < currentNode.key) {
                    currentNode = currentNode.leftChild;
                    if (currentNode == null) {
                        // Размещаем узел в необходимом месте
                        parent.leftChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    currentNode = currentNode.rightChild;
                    if (currentNode == null) {
                        // Размещаем узел в необходимом месте:
                        parent.rightChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Обход узла в порядке возростания ключей
    public void traverseTree(Node currentNode) {
        if (currentNode != null) {
            traverseTree(currentNode.leftChild);
            System.out.println(currentNode);
            traverseTree(currentNode.rightChild);
        }
    }

    public void traverseTree() {
        traverseTree(root);
    }

    // Поиск узла по ключу
    public Node findNode(int key) {
        Node focusNode = root;
        while (focusNode.key != key) {
            if (key < focusNode.key) {
                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
            }
            else {
                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
            }
            // Не нашли:
            if (focusNode == null) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return focusNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Удаления **чего**?

Comment: @Эникейщик ключа

Comment: Может удаление узла по ключу?

Comment: @yno7 Да, именно так :) Не знал, как сформулировать правильно, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Apolomir что по-вашему должно произойти с деревом после удаления не листового узла? должно ли дерево поддерживать какую то структуру(например быть сортирующим деревом)? как вы добавляете в него элементы?

Comment: @VladMamaev Добавил остальную часть кода для ясности. После удаления ключа, нужно снова пройти по всему дереву и вывести все его элементы в порядке возрастания ключа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот реализовал необходимое с помощью данных методов

```
public Node removeNode(Node root, int key) {
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (key < root.key) {
            root.leftChild = removeNode(root.leftChild, key);
            return root;
        } else if (key > root.key) {
            root.rightChild = removeNode(root.rightChild, key);
            return root;
        }
        if(root.leftChild == null){
            return root.rightChild;
        }
        else if(root.rightChild == null){
            return root.leftChild;
        }
        else {
            int min_key = find_min(root.rightChild).key;
            root.key = min_key;
            root.rightChild = removeNode(root.rightChild, min_key);
            return root;
        }
    }

    public Node find_min(Node root) {
        if (root.leftChild != null) {
            return find_min(root.leftChild);
        } else {
            return root;
        }
    }
```